# How to modify MVC 4 Routing Table for Different Users?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am fairly new to ASP to MVC, and I need help to setup routes.  I am building a site that has two types of users (Seller & Buyers). Depending on which user logs in, I want the system to take them to their appropriate controller and action method.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to have different routing for the different user types.

Simply define a route for each user type (/seller, /buyer) and redirect them accordingly.

For security measure, you might want to add the Authorization attribute and specify a role so that only user in the appropriate roles can access that section.